# Remove listbox item

Tags: c#

**Just help with this situation:

listbox1 loads items from text.txt lines on startup

textbox1

addbutton could add a new item to listbox data from textbox1

removebutton could remove a item lisbox**

I just remove the item added by addbutton but I can't remove item loaded from txt file
Any Simple Winform? Thanks

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry. I've fixed my question

Comment: see in msdn [items.addrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx), [listbox.items.add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx), [items.clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx), [items.remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) and [items.removeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you really want, but here's an example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load text file lines into listBox
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourFileFromWorkingDirectory.txt");
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add new line from textBox
    if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty) { listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text); }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove selected line in listBox
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

You can load data from text files with this and remove unwanted lines from listBox. If you want you can go even further:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save listBox into text file
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("yourFileFromWorkingDirectory.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

That'll save everything from your listBox. I hope it helps.

Comment: In some ways, can you use DataSource or DataBinding for this application?

Comment: Well you would have to edit some lines, but the main idea behind it would be the same. I never used those classes before, so I can't give you an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little broad in scope, not sure if you just want to know how to remove an item, add an item or add items from a text file. I will address the first two. Both functions you are wanting are part of the ListBox's Item [`ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is a simplistic example on how to add a textbox's Text to a Listbox and how to remove the ListBox's SelectedItem.

```
private void AddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
}

private void RemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

---

Responding to your comment you can always test for the presence of the item then delete it. This code works for me also.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I did the listbox with items loaded from a text file but I can't remove any item in this list box, so if you have any idea, pls help

Comment: Just make sure the item you want to delete has been selected, I just did a test and it will remove a selectedItem